# WFFM Form field is null

Tags: wffm

I am trying to get the value of WFFM form fields in code on submit button click. I tried `Request.Form["First Name"]`. but I am getting `null` for all field names even if the field has data. Can anyone please suggest how I can get field (text or checkbox) value. I am using the code below:

```
var nameField = this.Form.Fields.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "First Name");
if(nameField != null && Request.Form["First Name"] != null)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using WFFM custom save action, so your Execute method should look like:

```
public void Execute(ID formid, AdaptedResultList fields, params object[] data)
```

What you can do to get the value of a field is to use the fields **AdaptedResultList** and create a helper method like:

```
private string GetValue(string formFieldId, AdaptedResultList fields)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formFieldId))
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (fields == null || fields.GetEntryByID(formFieldId) == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return fields.GetValueByFieldID(formFieldId);
}
```

and then you call it as:

```
var FirstName = GetValue("First Name", fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the value from the FormSubmitContext object vs this. :

```
var postedFormData = formSubmitContext.PostedFormData;
var nameField = postedFormData.Fields.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals("First Name");
if(nameField != null)
{
 ...
}
```

And check this out: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2017/10/sitecore-9-forms-custom-submit-action.html

Let me know if that helps!